# Cannot convert value of type 'NSDictionary.Iterator.Element' (aka '(key: Any, value: Any)') to expected argument type 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am facing error on 7th line it's giving "Cannot convert value of type'NSDictionary.Iterator.Element' (aka '(key: Any, value: Any)') to expected argument type 'NSDictionary'".

```
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    ref = snapshot.ref
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

    if (snapshotValue["visitor"] != nil) {
        for item in snapshotValue["visitor"] as! NSDictionary {
            visitor = UserVisitor.init(visitorData: item)
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is `snapshotValue` defined ?

Comment: Also you should be able to write Swift without ever having to cast to `NSDictionary`. try removing  `as! NSDictionary` in the first place.

Comment: @deadbeef when i removing it gives this error "Type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'"

Comment: On which line is it giving an error?  The third line is `ref = snapshot.ref`.

Comment: You are iterating a dictionary using array syntax.

Comment: is `snapshotValue["visitor"]` a dictionary or an array ?

Comment: @vadian actually snapshotValue["visitor"] is an array of dictioanry.Please refer the image i have uploaded

Comment: What type does your UserVisitor expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a pure Swift approach like this :

```
// snapshotValue is a dictionary
if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
    // The content of the "visitor" key is a dictionary of dictionaries
    if let visitorDictionary = snapshotValue["visitor"] as? [String:[String:Any]] {
        for (visitorId, visitorData) in visitorDictionary {
            // This assumes that your initializer for UserVisitor is
            // init(visitorData: [String:Any]) { ... }
            visitor = UserVisitor.init(visitorData: visitorData)
        }
    }
}
```

Try not using `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` unless you really need to. Native Swift types work better in Swift...

You can write the else statements to handle data that is not in the expected format.

Comment: @rahul-gupta There was a mistake in my answer which I just fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`snapshotValue["visitor"]` is obviously an array so cast it to Swift Array containing dictionaries:

```
if let visitors = snapshotValue["visitor"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for item in visitors {
        visitor = UserVisitor(visitorData: item)
    }
}
```